# What was the relative velocity of Kosmos-2004 and the ChangZheng rocket stage at their closest aproach?

Tags: debris, conjunction

Yesterday (15th October 2020), Kosmos-2004 and a ChangZheng rocket stage were predicted to pass within 25 metres of each other and the media was quick to report the possibility of a collision.  [They appear to have safely passed each other](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-54562501).  If they had collided the amount of debris would have depended, indirectly, on their impact velocity.  So how fast were they travelling relative to each other?

Comment: It's in the article you linked "relative velocity of 14.66km/s"

Comment: @OrganicMarble  Doh!  How could I miss that???  I was so busy reading the predictions of doom that I must have skimmed over the article describing what actually happened!  -1 to me

Comment: You got it independently confirmed, with calculations, by a good answer to your question, so remove that -1!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LeoLabs [tweet](https://twitter.com/LeoLabs_Space/status/1316147305125490694):

> We are monitoring a very high risk conjunction between two large defunct objects in LEO. Multiple data points show miss distance <25m and Pc between 1% and 20%. Combined mass of both objects is ~2,800kg.
>
> - Object 1: 19826
> - Object 2: 36123
> - TCA: Oct 16 00:56UTC
> - Event altitude: 991km

---

From https://www.n2yo.com/

```
COSMOS 2004:
1 19826U 89017A   20289.94725126 +.00000031 +00000-0 +17799-4 0  9999
2 19826 082.9564 008.1177 0029070 239.7148 310.5690 13.72296120584529

CZ-4C R/B:
1 36123U 09072C   20289.93627684 -.00000054 +00000-0 -75953-5 0  9994
2 36123 100.3629 201.1010 0156470 236.9981 239.7964 13.46117612532354
```

---

I put those TLEs into Skyfield and for the conjunction I got

#### speed:  14.45 km/s

#### angle:  166.6 degrees

so it was close to 180 degrees, they were coming almost right at each other!

[image: satellite conjunction]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skyfield.api import Topos, Loader, EarthSatellite

TLEs = """1 19826U 89017A   20289.94725126 +.00000031 +00000-0 +17799-4 0  9999
2 19826 082.9564 008.1177 0029070 239.7148 310.5690 13.72296120584529
1 36123U 09072C   20289.93627684 -.00000054 +00000-0 -75953-5 0  9994
2 36123 100.3629 201.1010 0156470 236.9981 239.7964 13.46117612532354"""
lines = TLEs.splitlines()

load = Loader('~/Documents/fishing/SkyData')  # avoids multiple copies of large files
ts = load.timescale() # include builtin=True if you want to use older files (you may miss some leap-seconds)
eph = load('de421.bsp')
earth = eph['earth']

minutes = np.arange(0, 121, 0.1)

times = ts.utc(2020, 10, 16, 0, minutes)
COSMOS = EarthSatellite(lines[0], lines[1]).at(times)
CZ4C = EarthSatellite(lines[2], lines[3]).at(times)

COSMOS_pos, CZ4C_pos = [x.position.km for x in (COSMOS, CZ4C)]
COSMOS_vel, CZ4C_vel = [x.velocity.km_per_s for x in (COSMOS, CZ4C)]

dv = CZ4C_vel - COSMOS_vel
dpos = CZ4C_pos - COSMOS_pos
rel_speed = np.sqrt((dv**2).sum(axis=0))
distance = np.sqrt((dpos**2).sum(axis=0))

COSMOS_vnorm, CZ4C_vnorm = [v / np.sqrt((v**2).sum(axis=0)) for v in (COSMOS_vel, CZ4C_vel)]
angle = np.arccos((COSMOS_vnorm * CZ4C_vnorm).sum(axis=0))

COSMOS_height, CZ4C_height = [np.sqrt((p**2).sum(axis=0)) - 6378.137 for p in (COSMOS_pos, CZ4C_pos)]

print('max speed: ', rel_speed[40:80].max())
print('max angle: ', (180/np.pi) * angle[40:80].max())

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
plt.plot(minutes, distance)
plt.ylabel('separation  (km)')
plt.ylim(0, None)
plt.xlim(0, 120)

plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
plt.plot(minutes, rel_speed)
plt.ylabel('relative speed (km/sec)')
plt.ylim(0, None)
plt.xlim(0, 120)

plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
plt.plot(minutes, (180/np.pi) * angle)
plt.ylabel('angle (deg)')
plt.ylim(0, None)
plt.xlim(0, 120)

plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
plt.plot(minutes, COSMOS_height)
plt.plot(minutes, CZ4C_height)
plt.ylabel('altitude (km)')
plt.xlabel('minutes since 2020-10-16 00:00 UTC')
plt.xlim(0, 120)
plt.show()
```

Comment: +
1, great answer, thanks very much.  Are those Python modules freely available, they look very useful?

Comment: @DaveGremlin I'm confused, I never heard of one that wasn't! I usually add a [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) link but it's getting so popular now. It's just the usual pip install. The [developer is fantastic](https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield) and there's quite a community of people expanding its capabilities. They can even pronounce [ephemerides](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/370655/217285)! It can pull in TLEs and asteroids and comets and star calatalogs as well as the JPL ephemerides.